# ElasticSearch - How to get subaggregation data from jest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I made some elastic query like below.

```
"aggregations": {
      "state": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "events"
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "by_act": {
               "cardinality": {
                  "field": "events.activityoid"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "by_event": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "eventcnt"
         }
      }
```

And here is part of result.

```
"aggregations": {
      "by_event": {
         "value": 132
      },
      "state": {
         "doc_count": 1874,
         "by_act": {
            "value": 12
         },
```

I can get 'by_event' value with

> result.getAggregations().getCardinalityAggregation(
>   "by_cases").getCardinality();

But Don't know How to get 'by_act' value, since it's not in bucket.
Any idea of this?

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your code in order to see how to navigate within the results and get what you want?

Comment: I did. there is result data in result.getAggregations().getTermsAggregation( "state").jsonRoot, but cannot get them out with jest.